# Using value in cell to reference sheet in conjunction w/ 'arrayformula' function

Tags: google-sheets

In cell A4 I have name of sheet (e.g. Sheet1) w/ data values in cells B10:K10 that I would like to copy into cells C4:L4 of current sheet.

I'd like to use `arrayformula` function, however, I am having trouble getting function to recognize a valid 'sheet name'.

In cell C4, tried using `=arrayformula('A4'!B$10:K$10)`

I've also tried using 'indirect' function which works fine by itself (e.g. `=indirect(C4&"!B$10")`) for a single cell copy.

How can I merge both indirect and arrayformula together to get bulk 'live' copy to take effect?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `arrayformula` to do this. Just enter

```
=indirect(C4&"!B$10:K$10")
```

and you're done. This is an example of how

> Many array formulas will be automatically expanded into neighboring cells, obviating the explicit use of ARRAYFORMULA  -- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en